# PBI - Export underlying data want have all of the columns

Tags: export, powerbi

I'm trying to export columns with **Underlying export** but export from different visuals has different results even though it should always contain the same columns.

So far I did dig up on internet that I have to:

1. add all desired columns for export to Fact table as new columns (if they are metrics, convert them to columns and to text, if they are in different Dimension type table, use in Fact table in new column function RELATE and add the concrete metric/column so you would have all of them in Fact table and as columns with text type.
2. allow in your settings the Underlying export,
3. profit?

But so far no luck.

I did notice if I do the export from a visual in Fact table, I have all the columns ( all wanted exported colums not being in Fact table added to the Fact table with RELATED function as new columns ), but if I do the export from a visual being in Dimension table, the only columns I see are from that concrete Dimension table. Even if they do have a connection with each other and both have IDs with no duplications.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you show some examples of what you're getting versus what you are trying to get?

Comment: NDA - I can't. 
When you click "3 dots" in a upper right corner of a visual and select export, and then export underlying data, my export does contain all the columns which should be exporting only if the visual is from Fact table. Even if visuals from different tables are connected with this Fact table.

I hope it's more clear.

Comment: You don't have to show your actual data, just something sufficiently representative so we know what you're talking about. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s are super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you cant export date columns from export data in visuals you need to make duplicates of the date column you would like exported and change the format to text they will than appear in your export

Comment: You CAN export date columns, regardless of the format.